# asp.net checkbox event not firing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

I have a checkbox on a form:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"
Visible="true" AutoPostBack="True" oncheckedchanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
```

It is not firing the below event when I check or uncheck it.

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox1.Checked)
    {
        preContactTextBox.Visible = true;
        prePracticeCodeTextBox.Visible = true;            
    }
    else
    {
        preContactTextBox.Visible = false;
        prePracticeCodeTextBox.Visible = false;            
    }
}
```

It is not entering this event at all. What I am doing wrong?

here's the complete code:

http://pastebin.com/amQURr91

How can I get it to fire the event?

Comment: the problem might be with the viewstate or the postback event.

Comment: @vinay how do i change viewstate? what should i do wtih it

Comment: Did you check with FireBug or some other javascript debugger if you have a javascript error in the page?

Comment: @onof yes i did check and there are no errors

Comment: here is what the code looks like after browser interprets it   <dl>
204 <dt><label for="CheckBox1">PreAnalytical?</label></dt>
205 <dd> <span OnCheckChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"><input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="CheckBox1" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'CheckBox1\',\'\')', 0)" /></span></dd>
206 </dl>
207

Comment: @onof please join our meeting http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3451/discussion-between-i-and-james-johnson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the postback is not firing due to the niceforms plugin you are using. It seems the plugin is overriding the default functionality of the checkbox.

To test if this is the case trying removing the `class="niceform"` attribute from your form tag.

Due to the fact that smartforms override the onclick event, as far as I can tell the only way to resolve this is to modify the source of the niceforms plugin by replacing the inputCheck function with the following. I have tested this and it worked for me.

```
function inputCheck(el) { //extend Checkboxes
    el.oldClassName = el.className;
    el.dummy = document.createElement('img');
    el.dummy.src = imagesPath + "0.png";
    if (el.checked) { el.dummy.className = "NFCheck NFh"; }
    else { el.dummy.className = "NFCheck"; }
    el.dummy.ref = el;
    if (isIE == false) { el.dummy.style.left = findPosX(el) + 'px'; el.dummy.style.top = findPosY(el) + 'px'; }
    else { el.dummy.style.left = findPosX(el) + 4 + 'px'; el.dummy.style.top = findPosY(el) + 4 + 'px'; }
    el.dummy.onclick = function () {
        //Set the checked state of the checkbox
        this.ref.checked = this.ref.checked ? false : true;
        //Fire the postback
        this.ref.click();
        if (!this.ref.checked) {
            this.ref.checked = true;
            this.className = "NFCheck NFh";
        }
        else {
            this.ref.checked = false;
            this.className = "NFCheck";
        }
    }
    el.onfocus = function () { this.dummy.className += " NFfocused"; }
    el.onblur = function () { this.dummy.className = this.dummy.className.replace(/ NFfocused/g, ""); }
    el.init = function () {
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(this.dummy, this);
        el.className = "NFhidden";
    }
    el.unload = function () {
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this.dummy);
        this.className = this.oldClassName;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @jdavis im sorry but can you show me how i would incorporate this into my code

Comment: No worries, glad to help. With regards to what's changed. I removed the onclick override (which didn't seem to have any adverse effect) and added the commented lines of code (see: `//Set the checked state of the checkbox` and `//Fire the postback`).

Answer (score 4):

The CheckedChanged event of Checkbox control raises only if the **AutoPostBack** property of checkbox is specified with value "true".

Answer (score 2):

I would check to make sure that you don't have validation somewhere that's preventing the event from firing. I don't see anything wrong with the code, so validation is the next most likely culprit.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" ... />
```

Comment: required field validators and the like.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Are any of the events on the page firing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3451/discussion-between-i-and-james-johnson)

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion is to store the checkbox in a tempcheck box and check if the tempcheck is true or false.
If this checkbox is in a formedit, then you need a directcast and find control on the field.
Protected Sub ckbCheckBox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim tempChk As CheckBox
        Try
            tempChk = DirectCast(YourFormView.FindControl("ckbCheckBox"), CheckBox)
            If tempChk.Checked = True Then
               'do something
            Else
                do something
            End If

```
    Catch ex As Exception
        lblErrorMessage.Text = " Error occurred during ckbCheckBox.  Following are the errors: <br> " & ex.ToString
    End Try

End Sub
```